# Convert a Union object to a list of intervals

Tags: python, list, union, sympy

How can I convert a Union object in Sympy to a list of sub intervals?

E.g. convert this:

```
(-oo, a] U [b, oo)
```

to this:

```
[(-oo,a], [b,oo)]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
In [1]: var("a, b")
Out[1]: (a, b)

In [2]: u = Union(Interval(-oo, a), Interval(b, oo))

In [3]: u
Out[3]: (-∞, a] ∪ [b, ∞)

In [4]: u.args
Out[4]: ((-∞, a], [b, ∞))
```

Note: if *b < a*, then the interval union is *(-∞, ∞)*